# how to tackle this partial differentiation problem

Tags: partial-derivative

show that if $$f(x, y, z)=0$$ then $$\left ( \partial x \over \partial y \right )_{z}\left ( \partial y \over \partial z \right )_{x}\left ( \partial z \over \partial x \right )_{y}=-1$$

I don't know  how   to tackle this problem although I've tried.

Comment: Could you show your working then? There are many proofs of this online, but if you have your working and are stuck on a certain step, we can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

I could write it all out, but I think that what you are referring about is the triple product rule. A derivation can be found on:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule